# Draw a line along one continuous edge of a curved mesh

Tags: unity, c#, geometry, mesh

I have a rectangular mesh, but the mesh is curved:

[image: Example mesh shape, with an arrow pointing to the side I want to draw a line along.]

I want to draw a line along one side of this curvy mesh.

[image: Border/line drawn along one side of the mesh.]

Currently I can easily draw line along a side of a flat rectangular mesh by getting the mesh's min and max bounds. But what should I do to draw a curved line along the border of mesh from one of its side edges.?

Comment: Youe problem is not abvious. you can use bezier curve or curves like that to make curves. there are editor plugins for that

Comment: I want to make runtime line that highlight one side of the mesh. One side of a rectangular which is a curvy.

Comment: a line can highlight a mesh? how?

Comment: Want to try showing us a mocked-up screenshot of what you have in mind? A picture is often worth a thousand words when trying to describe a problem with geometry or rendering effects, and understanding the topology of your mesh could be important for a detailed answer.

Comment: @DMGregory A picture has updated in the question.

Comment: @virtouso No, a line will only display one side of the mesh highlighted.  Picture presentation added.

Comment: Does your mesh have texture coordinates? Can you show us how it's divided into triangles?

Comment: There are several meshes around 4000 objects. Model in 3ds max constitute with several triangles.

Comment: I have added one of the sample image.

Answer (score 0):

Finding spatially-related parts of a mesh - like which triangle edges sit on the outer perimeter, and how they chain into a longer arc - requires adjacency information that's not usually used for game rendering. So game engines like Unity don't generate / include that information by default.

That means our first step is to extract this adjacency info, by analyzing the mesh.

```
// This structure will let us uniquely refer to a particular edge,
// identifying it by the (unordered) pair of vertices it joins.
public struct EdgeID {
    public readonly int startIndex;
    public readonly int endIndex;

    public EdgeID(int vertexA, int vertexB) {
        // Put the vertices into a canonical order to de-dupe edges,
        // no matter the direction we're traversing it.
        if(vertexA < vertexB) {
            startIndex = vertexA; endIndex = vertexB;
        } else {
            startIndex = vertexB; endIndex = vertexA;
        }
    }
}

// Here we'll count the number of times each edge occurs in the mesh.
Dictionary<EdgeID, int> _edgeUseCounts = new Dictionary<EdgeID, int>();

void IncrementEdgeUse(int vertexA, int vertexB) {
    var edge = new EdgeID(vertexA, vertexB);
    int count;
    _edgeUseCounts.TryGetValue(edge, out count);
    _edgeUseCounts[edge] = count + 1;
}

void CountEdgeUses(Mesh mesh) {
    _edgeUseCounts.Clear();

    int triangleIndices = mesh.triangles;

    for(int i = 0; i < triangleIndices.Length; i += 3) {
        IncrementEdgeUse(triangleIndices[i],   triangleIndices[i+1]);
        IncrementEdgeUse(triangleIndices[i+1], triangleIndices[i+2]);
        IncrementEdgeUse(triangleIndices[i+2], triangleIndices[i]);
    }
}

// Here, we'll extract all the edges that occur only once,
// so we know they're on the perimeter.    
List<EdgeID> _perimeterEdges = new List<EdgeID>();

void GatherPerimeterEdges() {
    _perimeterEdges.Clear();

    foreach(var pair in _edgeUseCounts) {
        if(pair.Value == 1)
            _perimeterEdges.Add(pair.Key);
    }
}

// Finally, we'll gather all these perimeter edges and organize them into ordered
// loops and arcs of vertices.
public List<List<int>> GetPerimeterLoops(Mesh mesh) {       

    CountEdgeUses(mesh);    
    GatherPerimeterEdges();

    var loops = new List<List<int>>();

    while(_perimeterEdges.Count > 0) {
        var loop = new List<int>();

        int last = _perimeterEdges.Count - 1;
        var edge = _perimeterEdges[last];
        _perimeterEdges.RemoveAt(last--);

        int start = edge.startIndex;
        int next = edge.endIndex;

        loop.Add(start);
        loop.Add(next);

        do {
            int i = _perimeterEdges.FindIndex(e => { return e.startIndex == next || e.endIndex == next; });
            if(i < 0) break;

            edge = _perimeterEdges[i];
            _perimeterEdges[i] = _perimeterEdges[last];
            _perimeterEdges.RemoveAt(last--);


            next = edge.startIndex == next ? edge.endIndex : edge.startIndex;

            loop.Add(next);
        } while(next != start);

        loops.Add(loop);
    }

    return loops;
}
```

You can use code similar to the example above to extract all the loops of perimeter edges from the mesh. It won't behave the best if you have non-manifold geometry on the interior of your mesh (eg. 3 faces meeting along an edge), but that case can be handled at the cost of a little extra complexity, if it occurs in your meshes.

Given an edge or vertex to start from, you can search these loops to find its location on the perimeter, then walk the edge loop forward & backward to trace all the points along that perimeter. You can check the angle between consecutive edges to detect when you've hit a corner and should stop.

You can then feed those vertex positions to a LineRenderer to draw your line.